# How to refresh image.src dataurl, prevent cache?

Tags: image, caching, canvas, refresh, src

I have the following code that loads an image that I choose from files. It loads and draws it to a canvas, but if I make a change the the image file via an image editor, and then reload it- it doesn't refresh and show the changes(it uses the cached version)..

How can I get it to refresh??

```
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event){


        img[num] = new Image();

        img[num].onload = function () {

            //handle image stuff
        }
        img[num].src = event.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
```

Comment: I can load various images if their filename is different, but if the name is the same, it won't reload it.

Comment: Is e.target a form input element?

Comment: it is input type file:

<input type="file" id="imageReplacer" name="imageReplacer" />\
When the file is chosen, it calls the function.

$( "#imageReplacer" ).on("change", function( event ){ 
    replaceImage(event); 
   })

Comment: ahh.. I found my error.. it wasn't ccalling the change event since the filename was the same.. >_< now it is working when I clear the value from the input file element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, was an issue with the input file change event. Since the filename wasn't different, it wasn't calling the change event

If I add the line to clear the value, it works.

```
        $( "#imageReplacer" ).on("change", function( event ){ 
            replaceImage(event); 
            $(this).val('');
        }).hide();
```